# I want to include a php code in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

Here I have an `< a ...   onclick='show(); / a >`.  I want to add my php code to to js function, I mean to get action after click.

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/model/action.php');
?>
```

I'm going to put php code in this script

```
<script>
 document.getElementById("show").onclick = function() {show()};
 function show() {
  document.getElementById("numb").style.display="block";

<<<HERE>>>

}

</script>
```

Comment: What’s the question here? Did your attempt work?

Answer (score 1):

With the addition of jQuery you can use ajax function to call a php script

```
<script>
$.ajax(
  'request_ajax_data.php',
  {
      success: function(data) {
        alert('AJAX call was successful!');
        alert('Data from the server' + data);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('There was some error performing the AJAX call!');
      }
   }
);
</script>
```